# in binary max heap, isn't a parent node bigger than its children?

Tags: heap, minmax-heap

I got wrong on this question because the question says in Binary Max Heap, "If y is a node in the right subtree of node x, then y.key >= x.key." I attached the screenshot of the question below.

[Binary Max Heap Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiUYW.png)

if y is a node in the subtree of node x, I think x.key is bigger than y.key since according to max heap property a parent node is bigger than its children. I would like to know whether I am missing something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The "correct answer" in that picture is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Binary-Max Heap is one in which -

- The root node has the maximum value.
- The value of each node is equal to or less than the value of its parent node.
- is a complete binary tree.

> In Binary Max-Heap, a parent node is always bigger than any of its
>   children nodes

So you are right ! x.key is bigger than y.key since according to max heap property a parent node is bigger than its children is correct.

Comment: @jinmountain Happy to help ! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you are missing anything. Minheap bubbles up minimum key to root, maxheap bubbles up maximum key to root.

Now, [min-max heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap)... **those** are interesting.

Comment: Should I assume that the answer of the question is wrong?